Which was the first story to feature humans achieving immortality through science and technology advancements?
In 1956's Isaac Asimov's "The Last Question", in the future, humans were able to travel and colonize other galaxies and they also achieved immortality through science and technology advancements.
I doubt this was the first story to explore this idea.
Which was the first story to feature humans achieving immortality through science and technology advancements?

What do you consider to be "immortality?"  Does the body itself have to be immortal, or does body surfing count?  Does it have to be "true" immortality, or do things like endless aging (but not death) count?  What do you consider to be "science?"  Do fantastic things like alchemy that were somewhat "science" at the time count?  Does "lives forever but can be killed" count if the character is killed?

@davidw not aging

So Mary Shelley's 1833 short story "The Mortal Immortal" doesn't qualify because, as Wikipedia notes, "Winzy also discovers that he feels the effects of old age taking a physical toll on him despite the fact that his outward appearance continues to be that of a twenty-year-old. The elixir does not prevent the aging process, but only keeps the drinker from dying."

@user14111 I couldnt imagine a story with such an argument exist. What I really meant was not dying of aging. I would count that as valid

Are you counting for example early records of Greek Mythology?

@JiminyCricket. do they involve science and technology? I doubt it

I've not found one that did (yet). @Pablo

well, in the epic of gilgamesh, an alchemist is involved. A vital ingredient gets eaten by some sort of sea serpent though, so he doesn't actually achieve immortality IIRC - not sure if any other alchemist "elixir of immortality" stories exist where it worked, most of those go the "pursuit of immortality is foolish" route. Also, not sure if you would want alchemy to count as science ;)

@syndic Alchemy isnt a science but a pseudoscience

@Pablo Alchemy isn't a science now. Do we retroactively decide that things in the past weren't scientific whenever we make new discoveries? Was the plum pudding model of the atom not science?

@tashus Alchemy included practices which had nothing to do with the scientific method

There's clearly ones further back, but if you wanted to be more picky about the definition of the genre of science fiction, I'd suggest the Anton York stories by Eando Binder, first story in 1936.

@Pablo I'm not entirely sure that's true.  It entirely used the "scientific method" (basically trials in search of truth/procedures); yes most alchemists also "held whacky ideas" but by that measure all current-day physicists will be seen as nutjobs in the future. Newton was an obsessed alchemist of course, FWIW, and the "scientific revolution" is, essentially, all Newton.  FWIW alchemy is often referred to or described as a "protoscience" or "early science" I'd say.

@fattie "Their theories seem to have come not from science but from folklore and religion" - "relating alchemy to the mystical mathematics of the 64 hexagrams (six-line figures used for divination). Its relationship to chemical practice is tenuous" <-- some examples of Alchemy practices which had nothing to do with the scientific method https://www.britannica.com/topic/alchemy/The-chemistry-of-alchemy

1833: "The Mortal Immortal", a short story by Mary Shelley, first published in 1833, which you can read in her 1891 collection Tales and Stories at Project Gutenberg.
Wikipedia plot summary:

"The Mortal Immortal" deals with the cursed life of Winzy, a young man who has lived for 323 years. He recollects the events that led to his immortality. Winzy worked for the professor and alchemist Cornelius Agrippa. At first, he did not accept the employment offer made by Agrippa. However, Winzy's love for Bertha, his childhood sweetheart and love of his life, prompted him to accept the offer in hopes that the money he made could be sufficient to give her a comfortable living.
Cornelius Agrippa spent many days working on an elixir. Winzy was not aware of the complete purpose of the elixir, but he chose to drink it when he felt Bertha had left him for Albert Hoffer, a favorite of her protectress. Winzy drinks it in an attempt to cure himself from love. To his surprise, Winzy wakes up the next day rejuvenated, but with no knowledge of what he has consumed, discovering that Bertha is still true to him. Agrippa sets back to work, unsuccessfully, on the elixir once again since Winzy drank half of it and dropped the rest. Five years later Agrippa is on his deathbed and reveals the purpose of the elixir. Winzy has to live with the fact that Bertha is getting older while he continues to look twenty years old. Bertha is confused, but does not know the reason behind Winzy's continual youthful look. She believes that it is a spell that he must break in order for him to get old with her. Winzy confesses the truth and tells Bertha that he must leave her so that she may continue on with her life. Bertha accepts the situation and tells Winzy that she wants to start a new life with him somewhere neither one of them can be recognized.
Winzy and Bertha move to western France to begin their new life. It is here that Winzy witnesses the slow death of Bertha. He cares for her until she perishes. Bertha's death causes him to realize that there will never be another woman that he can love the way that he has loved Bertha. Winzy also discovers that he feels the effects of old age taking a physical toll on him despite the fact that his outward appearance continues to be that of a twenty-year-old. The elixir does not prevent the aging process, but only keeps the drinker from dying.


Yep, yep.  This is likely the one I had in the back of my mind when I asked about alchemy.  Nice job finding it.

That seems to be inspired by greek myth (Tithonus and Eos), but then most things are....

Frankenstein's monster appears to be immortal, despite thinking that it would die in the Artic.

1886: The Inner House, a novel by Walter Besant, available at the Internet Archive.

One morning—it was the morning of Thursday, June 2oth, 1890—there appeared an advertisement in the papers. By the telegrams it was discovered that a similar advertisement had been published in every great city all over the world. That of the London papers differed from others in one important respect—in this, namely : Professor Schwarzbaum would himself, without any delay, read before a London audience a Paper which should reveal his new Discovery. There was not, however, the least hint in the announcement of the nature of this Discovery.
[. . . .]
"Ladies and Gentlemen," said the President shortly," the learned Professor will himself communicate to you the subject and title of his Paper, and we may be certain beforehand, that his subject and matter will adorn the motto of the Society—Illustrans commoda vita."
[. . . .]
Therefore, when the Professor suddenly stopped short, after a prolix description of wasting power and wearied organs, and held up an admonitory finger, everybody jumped, because now the Secret was to be divulged. They had come to hear a great Secret.
"What is this Decay?" he asked. "What is it? Why does it begin? What laws regulate it? What check can we place upon it? How can we prevent it? How can we stay its progress? Can Science, which has done so much to make Life happy—which has found out so many things by which Man's brief span is crowded with delightful emotions—can Science do no more? Cannot Science add to these gifts that more precious gift of all—the lengthening of that brief span?"
[. . . .]
"You all know," the Professor continued, "how at a dinner a single glass of champagne revives the spirits, looses the tongue, and brings activity to the brain. The guests were weary: they were in decay: the Champagne arrests that decay. My discovery is of another kind of Champagne, which acts with a more lasting effect. It strengthens the nerves, hardens the muscles, quickens the blood, and brings activity to the digestion. With new strength of the body returns new strength to the mind: mind and body are one." He paused a moment. Then he gave the leathern case into the hands of the Director. "This is my Gift, I say. I give to my brother full particulars and the history of the invention. I seek no profit for myself. It is your own. This day a new epoch begins for humanity. We shall not die, but live. Accident, fire, lightning, may kill us. Against these things we cannot guard. But old age shall no more fall upon us: decay shall no more rob us of our life and strength: and death shall be voluntary. This is a great change. I know not if I have done aright. That is for you to determine. See that you use this gift aright." Then, before the people had understood the last words, the speaker stepped out of the Theatre and was gone.

